# <ul>のlist-styleのスペースを除去するには

Tags: html, css

`<ul>`について質問させてください。
デフォルトの`<li>`の先頭に付く「・」が邪魔で`list-style-type: none;`にて非表示させました。
しかし、非表示しているにも関わらず、その部分のスペースは取ってしまっているようです。
これを無くしたいのですがどのようにすれば良いのでしょうか？

```css
li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.ul_left {
    display: table;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ul_list">
 <li>フルーツ</li>
 <ul class="ul_left">
  <li>リンゴ</li>
  <li>リンゴ</li>
  <li>リンゴ</li>
 </ul>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ul` にpadding があります。
`.ul_left { ... }` (必要なら`.ul_list` も)に `padding : 0;` を追加すればいいと思います。

Comment: 無事に左に寄ってくれました。　ありがとうございました。

Comment: 因みに、W3C 標準に従って、[`dir`, `ol`, `ul` の要素は padding-left: 40px をつけています](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#lists).

Comment: @neuront 教えてくれてありがとうございます。　勉強になりました。